# jQuery UI checkboxradio icon incorrect on back navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a few simple checkboxes each converted to a jQuery UI `checkboxradio`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#my-form" ).find( "input[type=checkbox]" ).checkboxradio();
}
```

I can check and uncheck them fine, and they work as expected.

However, when I go to another page, then return to the page with the `checkboxradio` widgets on by pressing the browser back button, they all display the incorrect icon, and do not change when selected:

[image]

Looking at the web inspector, the background position for the icon is being overrode by the jQuery UI CSS:

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover {
    background-position-x: initial;
    background-position-y: initial;
}
```

The correct background position, which is crossed out, should be (if checked):

```
.ui-icon-check {
    background-position: -64px -144px;
    background-position-x: -64px;
    background-position-y: -144px;
}
```

This is an example `label`, the only difference pre/post back navigation being `ui-state-hover` is set on the first `span` when I return to the page, which causes the incorrect icon:

```
<label for="B21-2" class="ui-checkboxradio-label ui-corner-all ui-button ui-widget ui-checkboxradio-checked ui-state-active">
    <span class="ui-checkboxradio-icon ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-background ui-icon-check ui-state-checked ui-state-hover"></span>
    <span class="ui-checkboxradio-icon-space"> </span>
    14 Jan 2020 - 24 Mar 2020
</label>
```

How can I prevent the hover class from distorting the form icon? I have tried destroying and recreating the widgets to no avail.

**Edit:**

I have narrowed down the issue to it occurring in Chrome (not Safari) and when the `checkboxradio` widgets are within a jQuery UI `dialog`.

I can reproduce it in Chrome with the following minimal code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "#my-dialog" ).find( "input[type=checkbox]" ).checkboxradio();
            $( "#my-dialog" ).dialog();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-dialog">
        <label for="test">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test" value="test">
        <a href="page-2.html">Next</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `page-2.html` is any old page that, when loaded, you navigate back to `page-1.html` from using the browser back button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Now navigate back.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe how you are moving between pages and if any other libraries are being used. Based on the way you describe it, it sounds like it's not loading CSS properly or something is effecting the CSS when you navigate back.

Comment: I've stripped out all my CSS and JS and it seems to occur in Chrome (not Safari) when the `checkboxradio` is within a jQuery UI `dialog` -- please see my edit for an example.

Comment: I was able to replicate it. I had to click on the Radio button and then hit Next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I see happening, when you navigate away, the element is:

```
<span class="ui-checkboxradio-icon ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-background ui-icon-check ui-state-checked"></span>
```

When you navigate 'back', if you inspect it, you can see that `ui-icon` is being read with higher priority then `ui-icon-check` and the background position is set to `background-position: 0 0;` and this is the position of the first icon sprite.

I tinkered with the load order and each time it reverts the background position. Tested with Chrome 74 (32-bit) on Windows.

I think this is due to the way that Chrome is reading back the temporary state of the DOM in Memory. When you click the Hyperlink, the browser follows the request and starts rendering the new HTML or reading it from Cache. We assume when you click the "back" button, that Chrome is loading the content from cache or re-reading the HTML to render it. It's possible that the Class attributes are being read in a different order when being brought from Cache and this would explain why `ui-icon` is prioritized over `ui-icon-check`.

Not seeing a good way to test this theory. You could try clicking to page-2, clear your browsers cache, and then clicking back button.

I don't know that you will be able to overcome this. I did test by adding my own Back link and this works better.

**page-1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#my-dialog" ).dialog();
        $( "#test" ).checkboxradio();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-dialog">
        <label for="test">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test" value="test">
        <a href="page-2.html">Next</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**page-2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Now navigate <a href="page-1.html">back</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also present when you navigate back to the original page is the class `ui-state-hover`, despite not being hovered. I can get the icons to load correctly on initial load and back navigation by calling `$( ".ui-checkboxradio-icon" ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" )` immediately after creating them. It's not ideal but there's no better way that I can see. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: For anyone interested in future, I filed a jQuery UI bug report: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15342

Comment: @alstr Since this is only repeatable in Chrome and not other browsers, I don't think it qualifies as a bug for jQuery UI.

Comment: It also does it in Firefox, so that's 2/3 browsers I have installed. Regardless of whether it's the browser or jQuery UI actually causing the issue, I would suggest looking at alternative ways of loading the icons. If others disagree that's fine, but it caused me a lot of head scratching and wasted time, and there was no mention of this anywhere. I'm confused about why `ui-state-hover` is present, anyway, when no hovering is taking place.